# Publisher actions are not visible

Tags: salesforce1-app, publisher, global-actions

I have problem with publisher actions.  We just started using salesforce1 and I can't get my custom action appear on account screen.  I enabled chatter and publishers actions.    Enabled feed on accounts and contacts. Created a custom "add new contact" action for accounts,  modified account page layout to display new custom action.  Now I don't see it anywhere, not in slaesforce1, not on main UI.  Please help!!!

Answer (score 0):

How many Account page layouts do you have, and if you use page layout assignments - are you sure you've modified the right one ;) If there are many actions in the publisher - maybe you need to hit the "more" button.

If you're using S1 on a device you might want to go to main menu and pull down to sync/refresh. But - especially in initial stages of development - it's best idea to go to `/one/one.app` in your browser (just don't treat this emulator as absolute truth, you should still test on real devices).

Answer (score 0):

Do you have record types on the Contact object? If the viewing user doesn't have access to the record type, the action won't appear.